# How do I ssh tunnel port forward?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm on a Mac and I want to connect to an EC2 instance, then have that EC2 instance connect to a remote server over port 22. So as far as I understand it, I would do something like:

```
sudo ssh -l [USERNAME-FOR-REMOTE-MACHINE] -L 22528:[EC2-MACHINE-IP]:22528 -L 22:[REMOTE-IP]:22 [EC2-MACHINE-IP]
```

So I want to listen on Port 22528 on my local (I think) and somehow have that connect to port 22 of [REMOTE-IP].

I'm sure I'm wrong in so many ways, but any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I have drawn some sketches

The machine, where the ssh tunnel command is typed is called **»your host«**.

[image: ssh tunnel starting from local]

---

[image: ssh tunnel starting from remote]

### Introduction

1. local: `-L Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.`

   `ssh -L sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **local** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from the `connectToHost` machine.
2. remote: `-R Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.`

   `ssh -R sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **remote** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from your local machine.

### Your example

You want to connect to a remote server through the EC2 machine, right? Then the second image represents your scenario.  The `remotehost` is your EC2 machine. The `farawayhost` is your remote server with its pink port of interest (in the drawing port `456`, but in your case port `22`). So the command has to look like this:

```
ssh -L 22528:REMOTE-IP:22 EC2-MACHINE-IP
```

The port number of the green port is `22528`. Now you can access your remote server with ssh via

```
ssh -p 22528 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to forward local port 22528 (-L 22528) to connect to REMOTE-IP (:[REMOTE-IP]) port 22 (:22)

So it is `-L 22528:[REMOTE-IP]:22`

On the way you did it, you are forwarding connections to local 22528 to EC2's 22528 where there will be nobody listening, and connections to local 22 (which you may be not able to bind to) to REMOTE's 22.

No sudo for that.