# SSH tunnel via JumpHost and additional port mapping?

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel

I have the following layout.

- A (machine behind NAT/Firewall)
- B (server for reverse ssh connections - bastion host?)
- C (my laptop)

**A forms a reverse ssh to B**

```bsh
/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -N -q -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -R 22000:localhost:22 -C -i ~/id_rsa
```

**C forms an ssh connection to A through B (B is my jump host)**

I do this using the following ssh config (`.ssh/config`)

```
Host B
    ForwardAgent yes
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/b.id_rsa

Host A
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    ProxyJump B
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/a.id_rsa
    Port 22000
```

At this point I can type `ssh A` and I get access as expected to the server terminal.

Now I would like to be able to tunnel a tool (example Robo T3) to connect from my local using port 27000 to the MongoDB installed on host A and listens to localhost:27017.

What should I add to my SSH command (or modify in the config) to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post ([How do I ssh tunnel port forward?](https://superuser.com/questions/677944/how-do-i-ssh-tunnel-port-forward?rq=1)) I managed to find the solution which is quite trivial.

```bsh
ssh -N -L 27000:localhost:27017 A
```